# Google APIs Issue

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to implement a "signin with google" button from my website.

I tried both the javascript:

```
<script>
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            fetch_basic_profile: false,
            scope: "email" //I do only need the email for the moment
        });

        auth2.signIn().then(function() {
            console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
        });
    });
</script>
```

and "non-javascript":

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<script>
    function google(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
</script>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="google" data-onfailure="fail" data-theme="dark" data-longtitle="true"></div>
```

version.

---

But in both cases I get this error (as an error in the first script and as a log from fail() in the second one):

```
TypeError: this.u3.open is not a function
    at fv.open (cb=gapi.loaded_0:250)
    at gw (cb=gapi.loaded_0:298)
    at Dx (cb=gapi.loaded_0:341)
    at $w (cb=gapi.loaded_0:337)
    at xx.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:338)
    at new _.rk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:188)
    at xx.Ej (cb=gapi.loaded_0:338)
    at bx.a.<computed> [as signIn] (cb=gapi.loaded_0:321)
    at login:269
    at platform.js:28
```

I already whitelisted my domain inside the APIs developers console... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `ux_mode: "redirect"` to the *initializator/meta tag*

It becomes something like this:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            fetch_basic_profile: false,
            scope: "email",
            ux_mode: "redirect"
        });

        auth2.signIn().then(function() {
            console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
        });
    });
```

---

The problem is that now I cannot call `success()` of `fail()`.

I know it is off-topic but any help in the comments or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924325/google-sign-in-with-redirect) would be appreciated!